# ArgumentError: Factory not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to get factory girl to run with rspec in my rails 4.1.1 app.

Problem is when I run `rspec` in my command line, i get `Failure/Error: verse = build(:verse) ArgumentError: Factory not registered: verse`.

I am at loss because I checked the factory girl getting started page and many answers here on SO andI still can't fix this issue.

in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

my spec_helper.rb file:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

spec/controllers/api/verses_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "API Controller" do
  describe "show a verse" do
    it "should return status 200" do
      verse = build(:verse)
      get :show, id: verse.id
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
    it "should return json object" do
      verse = build(:verse)
      get :show, id: verse.id
      JSON.parse(response.body).should == {'id' => verse.id}
    end
  end
end
```

spec/factories/verses.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :verse do
    line1 "A beautiful verse I stand"
  end
end
```

Why isn't my factory loading properly? Files in the spec/factories folder are supposed to get loaded automatically.

Comment: it looks like everything is correct. Do you use `spork` or `spring` - if yes try to reload it.

Comment: I just noticed Rails 4.1 uses spring by default. I am new to spring, I tried stop and start but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: let's try to load `rails c` and execute `FactoryGirl.build(:verse)`. Do you have other factories? Try any of them too. Does any factory work?

Comment: This part of the issue seems to be fixed thanks to your suggestion and this post: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/88.

I added `config.before(:all) do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end` lines in my spec_helper.rb

I am now getting `Failure/Error: verse = build(:verse)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Verse`

Comment: add this as an answer because the problem is really weird and it will help others

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and although FactoryGirl.build(:verse) works inside rails c enviorment it wont work inside a spec file executed by "rspec" terminal command

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There seems to be an issue when using rspec / factory girl with spring.

Adding:

```
config.before(:all) do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

in my spec_helper.rb solved the issue.

Credit: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/88

Edit:

Another way to fix the issue is to manually tell Factory Girl where to load the factory. Add this in your spec_helper:

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and didn't even realize I was using spring. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Same problem with rails 4.2.0 and factory_girl_rails 3.5. only manual fix in rails_helper.rb worked.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thankyou! (I used the config.before block btw)

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be [an issue with Factory Bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/793). I fixed it (as per the issue report) with `FactoryBot.find_definitions`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.before do
    FactoryBot.find_definitions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not necessarily caused by Spring. There is an [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/issues/99) that means factory_girl loads the paths slightly different from rspec. The solution is to to add to the rails_helper the following

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'factories')
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

assuming the helper is at engine_root/spec.

This occurs when you are using rspec in a rails engine.