# How to test invalid_attribute using rspec and factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am learning how to test on rails from this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-the-first-best-practices-for-rails-and-rspec/).

On one part of the tutorial, it shows how to write `invalid_attribute` test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ContactsController, type: :controller do

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "create new contact" do
        post :create, contact: attributes_for(:contact)
        expect(Contact.count).to eq(1)
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not create new contact" do
        post :create, contact: attributes_for(:invalid_contact)
        expect(Contact.count).to eq(0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand where `:contact` and `:invalid_contact` point to.

Does `:contact` points to `Contact` class? It seems like it from [FactoryGirl's gh.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) If so, then how can I create `:invalid_contact` since there is no `:invalid_contact` class?

I have tried `post :create, contact: attributes_for(:contact, :full_name => nil)` but it still fails.

`spec/factories/contacts.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    full_name     { Faker::Name.name }
    email         { Faker::Internet.email }
    phone_number  { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    address       { Faker::Address.street_address }
  end
end
```

First test, `with valid attributes` pass. On model, there is presence validation  `validates_presence_of :full_name, :email, :phone_number, :address`. What do I add in order to pass `"with invalid attributes"` test?

Comment: `:contact` is a factory made with Factory Girl, you just need to create one for `:invalid_contact`, take a look here https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md and you'll see how to create it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the pointer @fanta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factory will use the class with the same name.  So your `:contact` factory will use the `Contact` class.  You can create a new factory for the invalid contact by specifying the class to use.

```
factory :invalid_contact, class: Contact do
  full_name nil
end
```

It's also possible to use traits to avoid having two different factories.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    full_name     { Faker::Name.name }
    email         { Faker::Internet.email }
    phone_number  { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    address       { Faker::Address.street_address }

    trait :invalid do
      full_name nil
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it with `attributes_for(:contact, :invalid)`

Comment: The first code works, but `trait` does not. The error, using trat, says: `     Failure/Error: post :create, contact: attributes_for(:invalid_contact)
     
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: invalid_contact`

Comment: To use the `trait`, replace `attributes_for(:invalid_contact)` with `attributes_for(:contact, :invalid)`

Comment: This is considered a bad practice, you have to include in the test itself the parameters that you are testing. Including it in the factory makes it confusing because you don't know what are you really testing and when the test fails you have to go to the factory to notice why is it failing. Additionally, changing the factory forces you change all the tests that depend on this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you link to says:

> Following the spec above, write a spec that uses invalid attributes to
>   create a new contact. This spec should check that the contact is not
>   created.

So you need to figure out how to test for `:invalid_contact` using the example for `:contact`.

You can just add a `let` in your spec:

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.
>
> Source: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Then your controller spec would look like this:

```
...
let(:invalid_contact) { create(:contact, name: nil) }

context "with invalid attributes" do
  it "does not create new contact" do
    post :create, contact: attributes_for(invalid_contact)
    expect(Contact.count).to eq(0)
  end
end
...
```

this way  `#post` action `params` are picked up from `invalid_contact`

or as @fanta suggested in comments, you can add a `trait` to your factory. I prefer my method because other people looking at your code will know why `invalid_contact` should be invalid without looking at the `:contacts` factory

Comment: Got the following error: `ArgumentError: Factory not registered: invalid_contact` I added `config.before(:all): FactoryGirl.reload...` as suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078768/argumenterror-factory-not-registered but it is still failing :(

Comment: oops, forgot to edit the arg in `attributes_for:`. updated